# Zero divisors in an algebra with two generators

Tags: algebras

Let $k$ be a field, and $R = k\langle x,y \mid x^2 = 0\rangle$. The elements $x$ and $y$ are not supposed to commute with each other. Is the only case where nonzero elements $a, b \in R$ satisfy $ab=0$ when $a\in Rx$ and $b\in xR$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is answered in Example 9.3 in the paper *Victor Camillo and Pace P. Nielsen, McCoy rings and zero-divisors, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 212 (2008), no. 3, 599–615*.